# Getting "cannot refresh user" error with symfony2 and doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have the class User as the base class then i extended Teacher from user class.

When i try to login i get this error

> You cannot refresh a user from the EntityUserProvider that does not
>   contain an identifier. The user object has to be serialized with its
>   own identifier mapped by Doctrine.

I have serialize/deserialize function in user.php as i have coped that from FOSUserbundle

```
public function serialize()
    {
        return serialize(array(
            $this->password,
            $this->salt,
            $this->usernameCanonical,
            $this->username,
            $this->expired,
            $this->locked,
            $this->credentialsExpired,
            $this->enabled,
        ));
    }
```

I am not able to find where i can check for error. i am stuck. please help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [code](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bridge/Doctrine/Security/User/EntityUserProvider.php#L83) of `EntityUserProvider.php` it seems that you have to serialize `id` of the user also.

Answer (score 10):

```
"You cannot refresh a user from the EntityUserProvider that does not contain an identifier. The user object has to be serialized with its own identifier mapped by Doctrine."
```

This is not the answer to the question, but if someone googles the error message above (like I did) this is the top hit. And since I found my solution, I thought I'd share.

You will get this error if you remove the current user from the database and then try to redirect the user. *(Which might seem like a silly mistake, but the error message sure isn't helping!)* The solution is to simply clear out the session before you redirect.

```
$this->get('security.context')->setToken(null);
$this->get('request')->getSession()->invalidate();
```

Comment: Thank you! I had that exact problem; removed user entity and tried to re-direct to login page and got the error above. Googled the error message and, voila! Landed here! You're effort saved me a ton more.

Comment: Pay attention: For Symfony 2.6+ you have to use `$this->get('security.token_storage')`.

Answer (score 1):

Just had the same issue using [class table inheritance](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#class-table-inheritance), it was caused by the visibility on the `id` property set to `private`, so the child class could not access the id, changing this to `protected` solved it.

Answer (score 0):

The User object get's cloned at some point, so be sure to **not** do this (as I did):

```
function __clone()
{
    $this->id = null;
}
```